# Компиляция нескольких java классов в консоли

Tags: java, unix

Помогите вспомнить команду для компиляция проекта java с несколькими файлами. К примеру, мой проект имеет структуру:

src --

```
    | com --

                 | example --

                                     | app --

                                                 | Main.java
                                                 | Utils.java
                                                 | Service.java
```

bin

Раньше пользовался командой, которая сама находила файлы в нужной папке и компилировала их. Сейчас никак найти не могу. Буду очень благодарен за ответ.

Comment: а системой сборки не хотите воспользоваться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для компиляции java-кода в байт-код вы можете воспользоваться либо системой сборки (gradle, maven и т.п.) или просто командой **javac**.

В случае с **javac** вам надо указать путь к "основному" java-файлу и тогда будут скомпилированы классы, которые в нем используются.

В вашем варианте будет так (находясь в директории **src**)

```
javac com/example/app/Main.java
```